# don't try to rebuild realm model every time run android build?

Tags: realm

I am using realm for Android. I notice that every time I run `./gradlew installDebug`, it takes some time doing some job `processing class xxxx` (xxxx is the realm class I use in my project). But actually sometimes I didn't change anything related to that, I was doing some other work(and it has nothing to do with realm).

So I am thinking is there a way to avoid rebuilding realm class every time, in order to save some time while building android app? like a flag I can add before build or something like that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed.  We agree and are looking into it.  The problem is that even changes outside the Realm classes can affect the code we generate for the Realm classes.  Tracking down those dependencies may be more expensive than just re-processing the code.

Comment: My suggest is there could be some command or flag that developer can add manually while building. As developer I know well that current build didn't change anything related to realm database( sometimes I just change color of a button) and it makes no sense I need to rebuild realm module again and again.

Comment: Will that kind of modification also affect `the code we generate for Realm classes` ? I don't know and just curious...

Comment: Probably not.  Btw, we are tracking the issue here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3034

Comment: nice to see that there is already an issue. upvote for your quick response and really appreciate if there could be some nice solution to this.